# How to check if Autoload loads only used classes?

Tags: php, class, namespaces, autoload, spl-autoload-register

Uisng [`spl_autoload_register`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.spl-autoload-register.php) for auto loading classes on my code. Example:

```
<?php    
spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) { 
    include 'my_class1.php';
    include 'my_class2.php';
    //...
    include 'my_classN.php';
});

$obj = new MyClass1();
?>
```

What if I used just class `MyClass1` in my code, does autoload loads all files or just `my_class1.php`?
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**  DO NOT use above code. Now I using [@Alex Howansky's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51954174/7199362) code with PSR-4 autoloading [specifications](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/).

NOTE: Autoload requires to use namespaces if classes located in subdirectory relatively to basedir ([see examples](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/#3-examples)).

Comment: With this code, the first time you refer to any class, it will load every class. In an autoloader, you usually just want to load the class referenced by `$class_name`.

Comment: It is syntactically correct, it will work. However, it is inefficient and misses the point of using an autoloader.

Comment: Thanks for reply, in this case how should load file only for used class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this code, the first time you refer to any class, it will load every class. This will work, but almost certainly isn't what you want. In an autoloader, you usually just want to load only the one source file containing the one class referenced by `$class_name`. Something like this:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {
    $filename = '/path/to/classes/' . $class_name . '.php';
    require_once $filename;
});
```

This obviously becomes very difficult if your source file names don't match your class names or you otherwise can't determine the source file names based on the class names. This is why you should use [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) naming conventions.

Comment: Thanks, with your example, when file name matches with class names but clasess     located in different path, i should use namespaces in each class file?

Comment: For example: lib1/MyClass1.php and lib2/MyClass2.php

Comment: The linked page explains this.

Answer (score 2):

Just as an addition, you can use the PHP function get_declared_classes() which will list all defined classes in the current script.